# Facebook login API javascript for mobile apps

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to intergrate facebook login for my app using Javascript. I have been successful following [this youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_gLILTRD_k) and I can login through the browser. However, on my android emulator, there was an error and nothing happened when I pressed on the button. On eclipse, this error was returned: "Uncaught reference error: FB is not defined at .../index.html" I am thinking that the probably is caused from the facebook developer side, probably the Valid OAuth redirect URIs or the domain names.
Question:
What should my settings on facebook developer be should I be using if I want to run this function on an app.

Here are my codes:

```
<head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
                <title></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
                <script src="common.js"></script>

                    </head>

                    <body>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    //initialize and setup facebook SDK
                      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
                          appId      : '201821216900862',
                          xfbml      : true,
                          version    : 'v2.7'
                        });

                        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected';
                                //  console.log('Logged in.');
                              }
                              else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
                                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in';
                              }
                              else{
                                  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= 'facebook not logged in';
                              }
                            });
                      };

                      (function(d, s, id){
                         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


                      function login(){
                          FB.login(function(response){
                              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected';
                                    document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                    //  console.log('Logged in.');
                                  }
                                  else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
                                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in';
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= 'facebook not logged in';
                                  }

                          }, {scope: 'email'});
                      }

                    </script>
                    hi
                    <div id="status"></div>
                    <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
                    </body>
```

additional info: the reference error only occured in the login() function, I do not have any domain names as I am using localhost,

Comment: No, if this was about Valid OAuth Redirect URIs or any of the related settings, the error message would be different. You have a simple JavaScript error here: You are trying to call a method of the FB object, before that object exists.

Comment: yea you're right! The error was not caused my the valid oAuth redirect urls but caused by one line "...style.visibility"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the login() function, `document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';` is not recognised. Error disappears after the line is removed.